How to publish messages to Kafka from another container
I'm using visual studio 2022 to create a containerized application.
When I try to connect to kafka I get errors like:
%3|1719311780.957|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap]: 127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT)
%3|1719311780.957|ERROR|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap]: 1/1 brokers are down
%3|1719311780.963|ERROR|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: rdkafka#producer-1: 127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT)
%3|1719311781.957|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap]: 127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT, 1 identical error(s) suppressed)
%3|1719311781.957|ERROR|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: rdkafka#producer-1: 127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT, 1 identical error(s) suppressed)
%3|1719311811.958|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap]: 127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT, 30 identical error(s) suppressed)
%3|1719311811.959|ERROR|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: rdkafka#producer-1: 127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT, 30 identical error(s) suppressed)%3|1719311780.957|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap]: 127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT)
%3|1719311780.957|ERROR|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap]: 1/1 brokers are down
%3|1719311780.963|ERROR|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: rdkafka#producer-1: 127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT)
%3|1719311781.957|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap]: 127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT, 1 identical error(s) suppressed)
%3|1719311781.957|ERROR|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: rdkafka#producer-1: 127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT, 1 identical error(s) suppressed)
%3|1719311811.958|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap]: 127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT, 30 identical error(s) suppressed)
%3|1719311811.959|ERROR|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: rdkafka#producer-1: 127.0.0.1:9092/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT, 30 identical error(s) suppressed)

My yml file for kafka and dependencies looks like this:
version: '3'
services:
  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:${CONFLUENT_VERSION:-latest}
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: 'schema-registry'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: 'http://0.0.0.0:8085'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: 'INFO'
  akhq:
    image: tchiotludo/akhq
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      AKHQ_CONFIGURATION: |
        akhq:
          connections:
            docker-kafka-server:
              properties:
                bootstrap.servers: "kafka:9092"
              schema-registry:
                url: "http://schema-registry:8085"
              connect:
                - name: "connect"
                  url: "http://connect:8083"
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    links:
      - kafka
      - schema-registry
  zookeeper:
    ports:
      - '50000:2181'
    image: zookeeper:latest
  kafka:
    ports:
      - '50001:9092'
      - '50002:9093'
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'INTERNAL://:9092'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'INTERNAL://:9092'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: 'INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT'
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: '1'
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: 'example-topic:1:1'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: host.docker.internal # change to 172.17.0.1 if running on Ubuntu
    image: 'wurstmeister/kafka:latest'
    volumes:
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
volumes: {}

I write the following connection settings in my VS2022 project:
{
  "Kafka": {
    "BootstrapServers": "127.0.0.1:9092",
    "SchemaRegistryUrl": "http://schema-registry:8085"
  }
}

Previously, other options were tried to specify BootstrapServers (localhost:9092, kafka:9092, localhost:50001, kafka:50001), but the errors remain the same.
Please tell me what is my mistake?


127.0.0.1 won't work between two containers. That's referring to your app container, not another one. kafka:9092 would be correct. 2) however, you mention "from another container", but that's not part of the compose file? Therefore, they aren't on the same network and so cannot connect. 3) KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME is a deprecated property. Have you tried modifying KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS also?


@OneCricketeer, thanks!
Indeed, the problem was precisely that the container was launched separately and did not see the host with kafka.
This solution was to add to the project file in the PropertyGroup <DockerfileRunArguments>--network NetworkNameWhereKafkaRunnedWithDependencies</DockerfileRunArguments>

Great! Feel free to answer your own question below rather than use a comment

This solution was to add to the project file in the PropertyGroup
<DockerfileRunArguments>--network NetworkNameWhereKafkaRunnedWithDependencies</DockerfileRunArguments>

